# Python - change module name, for more meaningful errors

Tags: python, python-2.7

Right now, I have custom classes I import like so:

`import lib.directory as d`

Then make an instance like:

`directory = d.directory()`

Then, in the process of using several of these classes in `lib`, I run into an error, say:

```
 File "./process.py", line 94, in <module>
   raise e
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 3 column 1 (char 597 - 677)
```

How can I change the `in <module>` part to something more meaningful? Where does that value come from?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File "./process.py", line 94, in <module>` means that line 94 in `./process.py` was not inside a function.  It was a module-level function call.  If the error was in a function, the function name would appear instead of `<module>`.